# Get all users by Role Parse Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

Hi I have the next problem:

I have 10 users registered in Parse,a user can have the role of Admin or Player.
I'm trying to get all the users first but when I tried, the query only return one (The current user).

How can I get all the users? And then how can I filter by Role?

I have the next code:

```
 ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e==null){
                Log.i("OK","no problem");
            }else{
                Log.i("NOT OK","problem");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: are you using _Role as the class and Role.users  of type ( Relation <_User> ) to store who has 'admin' and or 'player'  ? if you are then just do a relation type query on the role with name ( player OR admin ) and get the relation array in Role.users  for your user.list

Comment: I have a class Role with 2 rows with the name player and admin. There are 2 columns called relation<user> and relation<Role> is this corret? I have to add to the relation the users admin or player? How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, for something as simple as this, it would be better for you not to use relations and separate classes at all and instead to simply add a string field to the User Class called "role."  So go to your User class on Parse, add a new column of type String called "role" and then query it as follows.

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> userQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
userQuery.whereEqualTo("role", "admin");
userQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
  void done(List<ParseUser> results, ParseException e) {
 // results has the list of users who are admins
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check the ACL(readAccess) of each user. The user is without read access right. The other 9 user may not with public read, not specify the user's id, and the role is not equip access right.

As A.Vin's answer, if your user have more than 1 role, you can use array of strings.